# SPARQL Construct. How to assign the value of an RDF attribute to an actual RDF variable

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology

My query (excerpt) is roughly this.

```
CONSTRUCT {
?publication fb:type ?type;
fb:publicationType ?publicationType;
}
WHERE 
{
?publication a bibo:Document .
?publication vitro:mostSpecificType ?publicationType .
}
```

And it returns output similar to...

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://abcd.fgh/individual/publication12345">
    <fb:publication>Example pub title</fb:publication>
    <fb:publicationType rdf:resource="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/AcademicArticle"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Perhaps a beginner-esque question, but how do I tweak the query such that the output is:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://abcd.fgh/individual/publication12345">
    <fb:publication>Example pub title</fb:publication>
    <fb:publicationType>Academic Article</fb:publicationType>
</rdf:Description>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the assumption that the [`bibo` ontology](https://github.com/structureddynamics/Bibliographic-Ontology-BIBO/) is in the store you're querying, you can use its `rdfs:label` property in a [property path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/):

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?publication fb:type ?type;
    fb:publicationType ?publicationType;
} WHERE {
  ?publication a bibo:Document ;
    vitro:mostSpecificType/rdfs:label ?publicationType .
  FILTER (LANG(?publicationType) = "en")
}
```

The `?a vitro:mostSpecificType/rdfs:label ?b` is shorthand for `?a vitro:mostSpecificType ?something. ?something rdfs:label ?b`, without binding the intermediate term.